# Gearbox impact of skipping gears driving downwards

Tags: transmission

I have a driving habit that i guess is harmless to the vehicle, and i want to hear your opinions on the matter.

Sometimes i change the gears, for example, 1st then 3rd then 5th, when i am driving downwards, since it doesn't make the car choke.

So the question is, is it harmless to the gearbox to change gears in a non-sequential way?

Comment: As long as you match your engine revs to the speed of the gearbox in the new gear, then you shouldn't cause any additional wear than normal shifting.

Comment: Interesting note - many Corvettes (and some other cars) actually force you to skip shift from 1st to 4th (in some situations) in order to comply with fuel economy regulations.  Even when not forced, it's pretty common thing for drivers to do.

Comment: Do you mean down hill?

Answer (score 3):

You have a non-sequential gearbox and can select any gear you desire.  By design, the type of manual transmission you have allows you to do this.  It is fine and will not damage your transmission at all.

So long as you do not over-rev your engine getting back to first and you rev match the engine, as well, should not incur any damage either.

Best of luck.